# statement fails to write to mysql

Tags: python, mysql

In my project I am sending over two values via RF.   Within python I am split() these values into temp and location.  I modified the below statement to insert sensor.  Whenever I leave the sensor value in the below statement, my insert fails.  I turned on mysql log= but was unable to see the reason.  Any hints??

```
sql = ("""INSERT INTO tempLog (datetime,temperature,sensor) VALUES (%s,%s)""",(datetimeWrite,temp,location))

a = out.split()
temp,location= a[0],a[1]
temp, location = out.split (' ')
```

Comment: It seems you send two values for three fields

Comment: could you show the traceback that if any error is thrown

Comment: There's no access to a database _at all_ in your snippet so I fail to see how it could insert anything anywhere. There are other obvious problems too FWIW like having only two placeholders for three fields in your sql query, defining the `temp` and `location` names _after_ you try to use them, and not defining `datetimeWrite` at all.

Comment: sorry I didnt put all the code.  just put the relevant parts.  you are right where I need to add an %s to the VALUES

Answer (score 0):

err I believe my problem is with  VALUES (%s,%s) should be  VALUES (%s,%s,%s)